# Count the number of black pixels using ByteBuffer javacv

Tags: javacv

I have use this code..I am new to `javacv` and I need to get the pixels one by one in a region and get the color of that pixel. Can I please know how to do it using the `ByteBuffer` ,because byte buffer can read pixel by pixel and I need to check whether the pixel is black or white...

Can anyone please consider about this..I am really stuck here...

```
IplImage img=cvLoadImage("img\\ROI.jpg");


    CvScalar Black =  cvScalar(0, 0, 0, 0);
    CvScalar white =  cvScalar(255, 255, 255, 255);
    ByteBuffer buffer = img.getByteBuffer();

    for(int y = 0; y < img.height(); y++) {
        for(int x = 0; x < img.width(); x++) {
            int index = y * img.widthStep() + x * img.nChannels();

            // Used to read the pixel value - the 0xFF is needed to cast from
            // an unsigned byte to an int.
            int value = buffer.get(index) & 0xFF;

            // Sets the pixel to a value (greyscale).
            buffer.put(index, (byte) value);


            // Sets the pixel to a value (RGB, stored in BGR order).
            //buffer.putInt(index, Black);
           // buffer.put(index + 1, white);
        }


    }
```

Comment: Is there anyone who know about this can you please leave a comment here please.

Comment: Can any one give an answer please...I am at the deadline of submitting my final year project....can you please help me here..